# Looking for numerical methods for finding roots of convex vector function ${\bf f}({\bf x})={\bf 0}$

Tags: numerical-methods, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Consider the function ${\bf f}:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ defined as ${\bf f} = (f_1,f_2,\ldots,f_m)$ where each $f_i:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is twice-continuously differentiable convex in ${\bf x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

I am looking for a numerical algorithm to solve
$${\bf f}({\bf x}) = {\bf 0}$$

If there is a solution to the above equations, does any numerical method *guarantee* convergence to it?

---

EDIT: There is a result for the one dimensional case where Newton's method is guaranteed to converge to the zero for an increasing, convex function. Does this result generalize for the above case?

---

EDIT: We can additionally say that the $f_i$'s are quadratic, that is, they can be written in the form $f_i({\bf x}) = {\bf x}^{\top}{\bf A}_i{\bf x}+{\bf b}_i^{\top}{\bf x} + c_i$ where each ${\bf A}_i$ is positive semi-definite and ${\bf b}_i\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $c_i\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Is there any information about the size of $m$ relative to $n$?

Comment: We can assume that $n\le m$.

Comment: No constant terms? Then $x=0$ will work. What are you doing in your model to ensure that $x$ is nonzero?

Comment: Ah, sorry, typo, there are constant terms, I've modified the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your quadratic edit, here's an approach that is used with other non-convex quadratic problems. Let $X$ be a new variable, a square symmetric matrix of size $n$. Then your problem is equivalent to this system of equations:
$$
\langle{A_i,X\rangle}+b_i^Tx+c_i=0, ~ i=1,2,\dots,N; \qquad
X = xx^T
$$
These equations describe a non-convex set; but if we relax that last equation to a semidefinite inequality, we get a convex set:
$$
\langle{A_i,X\rangle}+b_i^Tx+c_i=0, ~ i=1,2,\dots,N; \qquad
X \succeq xx^T
$$
where $X\succeq xx^T$ means that $X-xx^T$ is positive semidefinite. To solve this, we first note that 
$$X \succeq xx^T \quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad \begin{bmatrix} X & x \\ x^T & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$
and consider this convex optimization problem (actually a semidefinite program):
\begin{array}{ll}
\text{minimize}   & \mathop{\textrm{Tr}}(X) \\
\text{subject to} & \langle{A_i,X\rangle} + b_i^Tx + c_i = 0, \quad i=1,2,\dots,N \\
                  & \begin{bmatrix} X & x \\ x^T & 1 \end{bmatrix} \succeq 0
\end{array}
If, when you solve this, you find that $X=xx^T$, then the $x$ obtained is exact. Otherwise, the value of $x$ obtained could be considered a candidate for a local search.

Because this is a relaxation, we know that solutions to the original problem are feasible points for this model. So, for instance, if $f(\bar{x})=0$ for some $\bar{x}$, then $(X,x)=(\bar{x}\bar{x}^T,\bar{x})$ satisfies the constraints of this convex model. This doesn't guarantee that solving the convex model will produce $\bar{x}$, of course. But I think there is reason to be optimistic this will work well.

Comment: An interesting and related paper is http://arxiv.org/abs/1109.4499

Answer (score 0):

If the functions are non-negative in addition to being convex, then you can try to solve the convex optimization problem
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{m}f_i^2(\mathbf{x})
\end{align}
You can use any known convex package. My favorite is [CVX](http://cvxr.com/cvx/). Check if your problem is expressible in their framework.

Comment: Unfortunately the $f_i$'s can be positive or negative.

Comment: Then I doubt any guarantees can be made. Despite the convexity of the functions, this is a nonconvex optimization problem.

Comment: @MichaelGrant Why do I need to formulate it as a convex optimization problem? I know Newton's method can be applied for root-finding, and in the one dimensional case Newton's method is guaranteed to find the zero for an increasing, convex function. I'm wondering if these results generalize, but I can't seem to find anything.

Comment: You do not need to, of course. But the fact that it is non-convex means that we know with certainty that a tractable solver does not exist for the general case described. For the specific functions you have in mind, it's a possibility, but still unlikely, since you've ruled out monotonicity.